# Is the function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $f(n) = 2^n$ computable in polynomial time using TM?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, polynomial-time

Assuming that the input $n$ is given as a decimal number.
I was asked to **prove** whether the function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $f(n) = 2^n$ is computable in polynomial time using TM or not.

My guess is that the function cannot be computed in polynomial time but I can't figure out how I can **prove** it.
Showing that the function can be computed in polynomial time is easy because we just have to exhibit an algorithm and show it runs in polynomial time.

I was trying to think about the problem a little bit but I feel like I don't have the right knowledge and tools when it comes to understanding the relationship between a function that can\cannot be computed in polynomial time and a language that can be decided in polynomial time ? and how it's related to the problem of $P = NP$ ?

My TA said that I should use a certain property that the function above has in order to show that it can't be computed in polynomial time, but he didn't answer the question about the relationship between computable\non-computable functions to decidable\non-decidable languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the size of the required output. How much time would it take you just to *write* the result?

And this has nothing to do whatsoever with P vs NP, or computable or decidable languages.